# Autolayout constant for Equal width constraint setting to negative value

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7.3

I have designed a simple view with some text fields, label and button, For my text field i have added a Equal Width Constraint for wC and h Any. But my xCode is showing up orange asking it to set to -60 value for constant, Can someone please help understand what does the negative value infer to and how does xCode suggest this value. Please see screen shot below.

Note :- my view looks fine with both adding 60 and -60.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a suggestion for your constant, rather it is indicating a misplaced view. Most probably you added some sort of constraint, but the UI did not update on the xib/storyboard file (which is quite normal).

It's basically Xcode's way of telling you, "Hey, even though the view looks like this in your layout, when it actually renders it will be 60 points smaller in width." To fix it in IB, simply select the affected view and go to **Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Frames** and the view should update accordingly.

If on the other hand you want the view when rendered to look exactly as is, choose **Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Constraints** on the affected view instead.

Answer (score 0):

The orange color means that the expected value for the constant is unexpected and is off by 60 points (So the expected value is 100).

When such a situation arises, you can either update the view's frame to adhere to the constraint or update the constraint to accommodate the frame change.

[image]